# How to extend JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']? TS2499

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

How come I can create a new type via `JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] & X` but I can't extend it?

[image]

I don't understand the error message -- am I not simply adding an "optional type"? What's the difference between extending types these 2 different ways?

Comment: `extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'div'>` works too IIRC

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was defining the type before hand

```
type SpanProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['span']

interface IconProps extends SpanProps {
  weight?: string
  src: string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use  [React-Markdown:](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown)

```js
import { IntrinsicElements } from "react-markdown/src/ast-to-react";

interface InputContainerProps1 extends Partial<IntrinsicElements['div']>{
  minWidth?: string | number
}
```

The Partial Class constructs a type with all properties of **IntrinsicElements['div']** set to optional.
Under the hood the Partial interface looks like this:

```js
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; };
```

Comment: Is that not just a re-export of the `JSX.IntrinsicElements` that comes with React?