# In a definition file, is it possible to extend from an imported module directly?

Tags: typescript

In a d.ts file, I'd like to do the following:

```ts
interface A extends import("some-module").B
{
   //...
}
```

The only way I've been able to do it is by importing the type I'm extending from first:

```ts
type ExternalB = import("some-module").B

interface A extends ExternalB
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your second example? Why are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, and it works fine.  I'm just looking for a cleaner solution that doesn't involve creating new types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't allowed, and as in the Playground, it gives error #2499.

> An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments. (2499)

This is also consistent with [similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56105006/1426891): You have to define the type first. As a hunch, this is probably for compatibility with the ECMAScript [`extends` definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends).

You can, however, do a type intersection dynamically. You can even [extend the resulting type as an interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604), assuming the result is an object type.

```
type A2 = import("some-module").B & {
    a2(): void;
}
interface A3 extends A2 {
    a3(): void;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiAzsxIAtCuplvAN4CwAUPPfJFDjvAEKW0PfwBGAFAEoAXPABuyAJbAA3FwYBfWkpq1JAOwAuIGADMoYBAEEAjPBAAPbeuCtJiAA7IYm-rnxESGEFkEA6Dgp4AHpg+GBkEFZ1ZE14AHdnAGt5eigTIVEJaTkaFU0ATwdjACZ4AF54eycXNzwCYlRvXwD4ADJOOgYoEszxKVllNS0dfUN4IwBmcysQG1YjMuoutMm+7MG82lowZHUcOPTRUwrO7nShShUFXN39w5Ljssrl897BK4AaVL5LimvbnsDvAoJNjtMXj8en8FN8ViC1h9-nDuAIkQCgA)

Comment: I suspected as much - thanks for the additional info.